# Is there a cleaner way to return just the first element from find?

Tags: ember.js

The following code will return a `DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`, but as the `slug` is unique in my model I just want it to return the first object.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('foo', { slug: params.slug });
    }
});
```

To get at the first object in my template I write `model.firstObject.slug`.

Is there a way to just return the first object from the Route instead of an array with one object? - and thereby only having to write `model.slug` in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises give you ability to chain additional promises to them, and the last/deepest result will be the result that's used by the model hook.

```
 return this.store.find('foo', { slug: params.slug }).then(function(results){
   return results.get('firstObject');
 });
```